# Jenkins Build Failing for Angular 6

Tags: angular, jenkins

I am using Jenkins for Angular 6 Project Build Purpose and getting below error:

> /app/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/temp/jenkins423226075999853444.sh: 27: /app/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/temp/jenkins423226075999853444.sh: ng: not found

I tried to add @angular/cli but no luck.
What's the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue using this command:  npm run ng -- build

Answer (score 1):

That's because **angular/cli** is not installed globally in your Jenkins environment.

Make sure you have **node / npm** installed and try building your project with `npm run build [--prod]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to fail to find `ng` in current work directory and  **PATH** environment

1) Add `@angular/cli` as a dependency into `package.json`

2) change `ng xxxx` to `node_modules\.bin\ng xxxx`